# What causes iOS to show the user 'low free space on device' when your app is launched?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

As my iPhone (ios 5.01) was getting low on space a warning would pop up as my app was launched to the effect of 'this device is low on free space' but not when I launched other apps.  What would cause that alert to show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a message from the system, I'd assume it's because you're using storage (i.e. writing data), and the other apps are read-only. There's no point bugging the user if there's no impact.